# How can I check if lists have the same number

Tags: python, list

I have a list with lists. I need to check if the first number of one list is  the same as the first number in another list. The same with the second number.

```
[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2],
 [1,0], [1,1], [1,2],
 [2,0], [2,1], [2,2]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide more information about your question? What have you tried? What about that didn't work?

Comment: What have you tried yourself. Showing *your* attempt also helps to clarify what it is you are trying to solve, although the problem description should in itself be sufficient. Are you saying you are looking for duplicate sub-lists, which you do not seem to have (you see, it's still not 100% clear)?

Comment: @Booboo I'm not looking for duplicate sub-list. I'm trying to figure out if lists contains the same first or second number. For example: [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2] have the same first number which is 0. [0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0] have the same second number which is also 0. These lists are being added to common list dynamically. I tried different for loops, but I'm newbie and I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done with list comprehension:

```
[x[0] == x[1] for x in l]
```

Comment: @user9829609 That's why you should be specific when you ask a question, otherwise it's just a waste of time for everyone, including yourself.

Comment: @TYZ Sorry, I was not specific enough. I meant first and second positions in two different lists